Substantiate the following statement " Arnoldi iteration is nothing but orthogonal projection onto Krylov subspaces"

Substantiate the following statement " Arnoldi iteration is nothing
but orthogonal projection onto Krylov subspaces"

My attempt
Let $K_n=[\vec{b} | A\vec{b}| ... |A^{n-1}\vec{b}]$ be a Krylov matrix. Let $A\in \mathbb R^{m,m}$
$$AK_n=[A\vec{b} | A^2\vec{b}| ... |A^{n}\vec{b}]$$
$$AK_n=K_n[\vec{e_2} | \vec{e_3} | ... |\vec{e_n}|-\vec{c}  ]$$
Assume $K_n$ is invertible.
Choose $C_n=[\vec{e_2} | \vec{e_3} | ... |\vec{e_n}|-\vec{c}  ].$
Therefore, we have $AK_n=K_nC_n.$
It is clear that $C_n$ is upper Hessenberg form
Every matrix has $QR$ factorization. So, we can write $ K_n=Q_nR_n.$
Hence,
$$AK_n=K_nC_n=AQ_nR_n=Q_nR_nC_n$$
That is
$$Q_n^{-1}AQ_n=R_nC_nR_n^{-1}$$
Can we say $R_nC_nR_n^{-1}$ an upper hessenberg form?
I know $R_n$ and $R_n^{-1}$ is upper triangular. Also, we know that $C_n$ is upper Hessenberg form.
Still I am unable to conclude why "Arnoldi iteration is nothing but orthogonal projection onto Krylov subspaces". Could you help me to figure out this?

Would you comment on my reply highlighting any points that remain unclear?

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and let $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Let $n \leq m$ denote the smallest $n$ such that there exists a monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ such that $p(A)b = 0$. It follows that the largest $A$-invariant subspace that contains the vector $b$ is $K_n(A,b)$. Moreover the Arnoldi method will (in the absence of rounding errors) produce a factorization of the form $$AV = VH$$ where $V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \dotsc & v_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ is a tall orthogonal matrix such that $$K_j(A,b) = \text{span} \{v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_j\}$$ and $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a nonsingular upper Hessenberg matrix with strictly positive subdiagonal entries. Let $$x_j \in K_j(A,b)$$ denote the approximation returned by the Arnoldi algorithm and let $H_j = H(1:j,1:j)$ denote the upper left corner of $H$. Your question suggests that $x_j$ has been defined as $x_j = V_j y_j$ where $y_j$ is the unique solution of $$H_j y_j = V_j^T b$$ and $$V_j = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \dotsc & v_j \end{bmatrix}.$$ It follows that the residual $r = b - Ax_j$ is orthogonal to $K_j(A,b)$ because $$V_j^Tr = V_j^T(b - Ax_j) = V_j^Tb - V_j^T A V_j y_j = V_j^T b - H_j y_j = 0.$$ Personally, I prefer to define $x_j = V_j y_j$ so that $V_j^T (b - Ax_j) = 0$, but with that definition the question become moot. The Arnoldi method is also known as the Full Orthogonalization Method (FOM).
